# Access inline style of an element in Angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

In have an Angular component that renders a span like this:

```
<span class="buy" [style.width.%]="percent"></span>
```

In my unit test, I want to check if the inline style has the right percentage number. For example, if the component renders as follows, I want to test if the percentage is 50%:

```
<span class="buy" style="width: 50%;"></span>
```

Currently this is the best I could do:

```
const debugElm = fixture.debugElement;
const htmlElm = debugElm.nativeElement;
const buyBar = htmlElm.querySelector('.buy');
expect(buyBar.getAttribute('style')).toEqual('width: 0%;');
```

I don't like testing the value of the `style` attribute to equal the string `width: 0%;`. Is there a better way to access the width property of the inline style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So people already talk about the solution and here is my thought.
Why bothering about the '50%' number though.
If your point is to test the width of '.buy' class to be 50% of something
we just simply

```
it('element with buy class should have width equal 50% of parent element', () => {})
```

and your test case could be(let me assume that you have a parent class)

```
<div class="parent"><span class="buy" style="width: 50%;"></span></div>

const debugElm = fixture.debugElement;
const htmlElm = debugElm.nativeElement;
const parent = htmlElm.querySelector('.parent');
const buyBar = htmlElm.querySelector('.buy');

const parentStyle = getComputedStyle(parent);
const barStyle = getComputedStyle(buyBar);
expect(barStyle.width / parentStyle.width).toEqual(0.5);
```

Here I'm just reuse the code of others above so not so sure the `expect` function could work. but I think this could be a workaround for your test case.

Comment: While the code is reused from the other solutions, your strategy is commendable. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
const style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(buyBar, null);
expect(style.getPropertyValue('width')).toEqual('0%');
```

Comment: So close! Unfortunately `getComputedStyle()` converts the percentage value to pixels, so the test fails.